# Find largest multiple for a number set

Tags: algorithm, methods, solution

An array of digits(0-9) of size N is provided as input. A set of numbers(N1,...,Nm) of size m with the numbers separated by space is also as the input. The program has to print the largest number that can be formed using the digits in the array of size N that is divisible by the numbers N1,..,Nm

**Example Input/Output1:**

**INPUT:**

160

2 3 5

**OUTPUT**

60

Explanation
60 is the largest number that can be formed using the digits 1,6,0 which is divisible by 2,3,5

**Example Input/Output2:**

**Input**

91028

17 5 9

**Output**

9180

**Boundary Conditions**

1<=m<=5

2<=N<=50

```
Can somebody explain how to approach this problem.
```

Comment: this should be moved to alogrithms section . It has nothing to do with java programming ..

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: Please provide other constraints for this problem ( how large is N, N1, ... ), and your current approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Try all permutations of all subsets of your digits, probably starting with the largest candidates.

If your factors contain `5` the *last* digit must be `0`or `5`

If your factors contain `3` or `6` or `9` the sum of all candidate digits muts be a multiple of `3`

If your factors contain 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 the last digit must be even.

And so on.